# How to debug random 404 errors in Angular when starting project

Tags: angular

Sometimes when launching an angular project, the home page (or any other) will return a 404. The issue is, the project was working fine and no code changes were made and this starts happening.

Last time, I added [(ngModel)]="something" in a div. Went to that page, no errors, everything fine. Closed the project and when I reopened, 404 error on the home page (not the page I added it to). Remove it and all is fine.

I am running into it again for at least the 5th time in multiple projects while trying to learn angular and have no clue how to debug it aside from randomly deleting code until the project runs properly.

Console errors:

> Refused to load the image 'https://localhost:44396/favicon.ico'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.   localhost/:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () 
>   localhost/:1

localhost/:1 seems strange to me since it's running on port 44396.

Running angular 8.2.1 VS 2019 preview, .net core 3

Comment: Does your project have a favicon?

Comment: Yes, the default one that VS creates with new projects.